# How are derived query methods implemented in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In Hibernate you can use the method name on a repository interface to define a query. I am curious about how this is implemented in hibernate, what does the generated concrete implementation use? Criteria API? Raw query SQL? Something else? Also when/how do these methods get generated? Is it when the app starts?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Hibernate but Spring Data JPA.

And it creates Criteria API queries.

You can checkout the code here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa